# Django or Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have made a certain app in Django, and I know that Django Rest Framework is used for building APIs. However, when I started to read about Django Rest Framework on their website, I noticed that each and every thing in [API Guide](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/)(like request, response, views etc.) claims it is superior to Django (request, response, views etc.).

The thing I am not understanding is whether these APIs will replace my existing Django models, views etc. or how can I use them differently in my existing Django code?

I am quite familiar with Django, but not able to understand exactly what Django Rest Framework is even after spending some time on it. (I know it is used for APIs.) Also, do I actually need an API? My app is able to send data to the server without an API, so in what case would I need an API?

Comment: They are designed to work together. DRF can build on top of your Django models (and Django authentication etc) - you use it instead of plain Django views in the places where you want API endpoints

Comment: @Anentropic So If I build my app entirely in DRF then both the things will be taken care of (The building of app itself along with API thing)

Comment: try reading the DRF docs, eg the tutorial here http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/#introduction ...it shows how you create a Django model and then DRF serializers based on the model, and then views and then an API based on the model and serializers

Comment: "also do I actually need an API" ...if you don't know whether you need an API you probably don't need an API

Comment: it shows you how the concepts fit together by giving a practical example... you can see the Django parts and the DRF parts and also goes from basic to a bit more advanced. I suggest to actually read it and try and understand what you are reading

Comment: @Rookie_123 you can try building some of the same stuff DRF gives you in plain Django and see if it's any easier.  Try making a bunch of JSON-ified query views for example in plain Django.  Then see if you can easily add another representational format.

Comment: The main benefit to using APIs instead of regular django is speed. With an API you don't have to reload the full page every time you make a change to something. Say you have a list of books displayed on one page with edit buttons. When you edit one with regular django the change is sent to the backend and the page refreshes. With an api you can use javascript .fetch calls to update the backend and repull the data from the api and refresh just a portion of your template instead of reloading the whole page. Makes for a much smoother and faster user experience.

Answer (score 55):

Django Rest Framework makes it easy to use your Django Server as an REST API.

REST stands for "**re**presentational **s**tate **t**ransfer" and API stands for **a**pplication **p**rogramming **i**nterface.

You can build a restful api using regular Django, but it will be very tedious. DRF makes everything easy. For comparison, here is simple GET-view using just regular Django, and one using Django Rest Framework:

Regular:

```
from django.core.serializers import serialize
from django.http import HttpResponse


class SerializedListView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = MyObj.objects.all()
        json_data = serialize("json", qs, fields=('my_field', 'my_other_field'))
        return HttpResponse(json_data, content_type='application/json')
```

And with DRF this becomes:

```
from rest_framework import generics


class MyObjListCreateAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]
    serializer_class = MyObjSerializer
```

Note that with DRF you easily have list and create views as well as authentication.

Comment: Your second example is incomplete as `MyObjSerializer` has to be defined somewhere, so it's not as "easy" as the example suggests (you can't get away without listing model fields etc *somewhere*). It'd be better to make the point that you can reuse the custom serializer in multiple views though.  So DRF helps with re-using code in addition to autogenerating a bunch of endpoints, format options, versioning...

Answer (score 51):

Whether you need an api depends on what you want to do. For example, if you want to access everything in your Django models from a mobile device AND a web-app, you would want to use DRF.

*Why*? Consider the case that you are developing an iOS app that users can sign into and you want to use Django as your backend. If you also want to have a website that they can use to change around their app's profile information (say, update their email address or upload a picture), you would need a way to share the information in your Django models with both a website *and* the iOS device. How can this be done? By giving the user the ability to create/read/update/delete data by simply telling it a url to go to. Now, if you want to access information from the model you can do it from multiple devices, since any device can visit a url.

However, if you're just building a simple webapp/webpage and keep it all in one place, you can just use straight Django.

Side note: it's a pretty popular opinion that you should try to separate your frontend from your backend as much as possible. In this case, if you want to use some frontend development framework like React, Angular, or Vue, it's gonna get messy trying to include all those resources in the Django template pages *even if* you only want a simple web app/web page. In this case, you would use DRF to set up your backend, and just hit the urls from the frontend using a tool like axios. In this scenario, your frontend would likely be hosted on something like Node.

Again, what you decide to use really just depends on what you want out of your app/site and how comfortable you are with each tool.

Comment: This doesn't really explain why prefer DRF over plain Django.  You imply with "By giving the user the ability to create/read/update/delete data by simply telling it a url to go to" that DRF can do it but Django can't, which of course is false.  You also suggest Django doesn't let you separate front and backend, also false.  I guess my point is you don't really explain how DRF helps with these versus just doing it in plain Django, which was the whole point of the question.

Answer (score 20):

The basic purpose of DRF is to provide APIs. APIs are the touch point in an app. Imagine a project where you have a Django wizard and someone on your team is a JavaScript expert and you want to develop mobile app. The JavaScript expert talks about web elements and threading and the Django expert talks templates and ORM, now what? API is your answer. Let Django wiz give APIs and JSON and let JavaScript wiz do his front end magic. Simplest answer I can think of.

Comment: This answer doesn't explain why DRF is better since API can be realized in plain django aswell

Answer (score 12):

In simple words,

**Django**:  provides features for standard web app

**Django Rest Framework**: provides features to build standard REST API.

Answer (score 5):

**Let's sum up,**

**Django** :

Tightly coupled with Django Templates.

**Django Rest Framework** :

Open for building views of my own choices with REST APIs.

Comment: It is incorrect to say django is tightly coupled with django templates. One can create api backend without using django templates.

Comment: That is where Django REST comes into rescue

Comment: I have created django api backend without django REST or templates.

Answer (score 4):

1. Do you actually need Api? It depends on your requirement and resources. If you only need a web application    then django provides everything you require to
   develop a web    application. If you need to develop a mobile
   application that will    communicate with a backend server then you
   will have to implement Api.    If you have remote iot devices that
   needs to publish its data to your    server, you will need Api. If
   you are good at frontend app    development,  mobile app
   development, and iot app development or you    have resources to
   have separate team for frontend, backend, mobile and    iot app
   development then it is good design to separate backend and
   frontend applications. To achieve this separation, your backend will
   be api based and your frontend, mobile and iot app will communicate
   with your backend using your backend api. With this design, any
   changes in backend will have minimal impact on your other apps.
2. Will these APIs replace your existing Django models? Ideally it should not but I am not sure if using drf will change your django models. I have not used drf to implement api. But if you just use django to implement your api, it will definitely will not change your models. You just need to define your api urls and api views.
3. Do you require external packages like drf to implement api endpoint in Django? No. You can easily implement Api endpoints using pure Django framework.
4. A simple way to implement api using pure Django.

   Define your api url -

   ```
   urlpatterns = [   
       path('get_all_user/',UserApiView.as_view(),name='get_all_user'), 
   ]
   ```

   Define your view

   ```
   @method_decorator(csrf_exempt,name='dispatch') 
   class UserApiView(View):

       def post(self, request):
           response_data = {}
           json_data = json.loads(request.body)
           response_data['user'] = YourMethodToGetModelData(json_data)
           return JsonResponse(response_data)
   ```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

the old school used **Jinja2 with html5, css3,** but this became inconvenient when **Single Page Applications** became popular.**API** helps to provide information more convenient for the frontend programmer. You no longer work with the frontend. The **API** is convenient when developing as Web applications and when developing applications for the phone.

Comment: What you have described above is server-side render and client-side render. As mentioned before, plain django can do exactly the same things as DRF

Comment: Of course Django can, but with DRF it is more comfortable to work and it has a lot of comfortable tools to work with API.

Answer (score 2):

Simply saying: with just Django you can create server side rendered websites; and with DRF you can create SPAs with a vuejs or react frontend part.

Comment: You can do all with Django only. DRF provides reusable classes, so we don't have to do lot of similar/repeated task.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link which might give you some insights on what you are looking for. This explains how a django app can be converted into Django Rest Service, and it also explains what a REST Service actually is

https://opensourceforu.com/2017/11/converting-django-app-rest-api/

Answer (score 1):

You can use django to build a complete web application, then what is the need of api?

Let's take a example for suppose at first you build a website for your startup using django. Your site grew popular, and for easier access in Android you thought of building a mobile application. Then are you going to maintain a separate database?  Nope, because not only it's difficult to maintain, but migrating the old data is also a headache. So here what django rest framework comes into play. You can set up apis to be used by your Android application, hence have to maintain a single database against multiple apps.

Answer (score 1):

My personal opinion is that DRF is more suitable for developing a website
For example, maybe in the future you need to use API. It is better to implement your website with this framework from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are building a web application.

In order to complete your app, if you want to code more python / Django code then use Django, to the contrary if you want to code more JavaScript code then use Django restful API.

For web application itself I like using Django ,because it is based on python ,it is much cleaner and shorter than js.