# Do i need to manipulate DRF if only im using the built-in template django system?

Tags: python, django, web, django-rest-framework, frontend

I have some troubles understanding Django and DRF, if for instance I want to integrate a frontend framework along with Django, do I really need to use Django itself or will I touch DRF; and in the other hand, if I use the built in template django system, do I need to use DRF? please someone help me since I don't know the answer yet since I want to integrate a frontend framework such as Angular to developer my web page but I think I don't need Django, instead I need to use DRF!

Comment: Checkout my answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/69540158/9384511

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) if you want to create/update/delete/read objects from/to a database. Django will enable you to create your [models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/) and manage them.

[DRF](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) will be used to create an API over Django.

If you want to integrate a frontend framework such as [Angular](https://angular.io/), you will have to query this API in order to retrieve data from / send data to the database.

There are plenty of tutorials on how to build a fullstack application, combining Django - DRF - and whatever frontend framework you like ([Angular](https://angular.io/), [React](https://reactjs.org/), [Vuejs](https://vuejs.org/),...)

Usually, it follows this schema (simplified):

Database ([PSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/https://www.postgresql.org/), [MySQL](https://www.mysql.com/https://www.mysql.com/),...) -> ORM (Django) -> API (DRF) -> Frontend Framework (Angular,...)