# Django Rest Framework for blog site

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to create a simple blog site using django where i also want to shere my product to show only. Is it needed to install Django Rest Framework here?
Can i see my website on mobile without rest framework?

I am expecting your help here.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I see your doubt.

##### 1. Your first question is "I want to create a simple blog site using django where i also want to shere my product to show only. Is it needed to install Django Rest Framework here?"

- Let me explain first. Django and Django REST Framework are two different things.
- Django is a web framework. Django REST Framework is a wrapper around Django.
- Django lets you handle backend and render frontend using its views and templates ([See Jinja Templating](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/templates/)). This means backend and frontend code remains in a single codebase. **Django can handle both backend as well as frontend.**
- On the other hand, Django REST Framework let's you separate backend code from frontend code. This is enabled because of REST APIs. You can serialize the data (Convert native Django Model objects to JSON or vice-versa), and fetch or push the data from frontend using APIs. Your whole backend will be developed using **Django REST Framework, it will **only handle the backend**, and will **not handle any of the frontend**.**
- In case of your project, you can do both. But if you want to scale it, using Django REST Framework would be much easier.

##### 2.Your second question is "Can i see my website on mobile without rest framework?"

- Well this question does not make much of a sense. What I think you wanted to ask, is whether after development, you will be able to view the website on your mobile.
- First of all, **to be able to view a website on the phone, it must be either hosted on local network to which mobile has access, some thing like `ngrok` or the website should be deployed publicly on a server.**
- Secondly, **Django REST Framework does not deal with website being able to be "viewed on mobile".** Whatever you are seeing on your mobile phone is frontend of that website. Which is out of the scope of Django REST Framework.

I think there were some fundamental doubts regarding both the frameworks. I suggest reading the documentation and some resources here.

1. Django - https://www.djangoproject.com/start/
2. Django REST Framework - https://www.django-rest-framework.org/
3. Difference in Django and Django REST Framework - https://apidog.com/articles/difference-between-django-and-django-rest-framework/
4. Similar question - [Difference between Django and Django rest framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68088101/difference-between-django-and-django-rest-framework)

I hope this clears your doubt. Cheers!